# update listview with different form c#

Tags: c#, listview

I want to update the records on the `listview` but it is not updating.

The `listview` is on `form1` and the textboxes are in `form2`. the error is

```
InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
```

Please Help.

**Form1:**

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateBook ub = new UpdateBook();

    ub.txtbook.Text = lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
    ub.txtauthor.Text = lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
    ub.txtpublisher.Text = lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
    ub.txtyear.Text = lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
    ub.txtcategory.Text = lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;
    ub.txtisbn.Text = lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text;
    ub.txtquantity.Text = lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[6].Text;

    ub.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Form2:**

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    books b = new books();

    exequery("Update tbl_books set NameOfBook = '" + txtbook.Text + "',Author = '" + txtauthor.Text + "',Publisher='" + txtpublisher.Text + "',YearPublished = '" + txtyear.Text + "',Category='" + txtcategory.Text + "',ISBN = '" + txtisbn.Text + "',TotalNumberOfBooks = '" + txtquantity.Text + "' where NameOfBook = '"+ b.lvbooks.SelectedItems[0].Text +"'");

    MessageBox.Show("Item has been Updated!");
    showlv("Select * from tbl_books", b.lvbooks);
    this.Hide();
    b.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have something  selected before updating.  So first check if anything  is selected.

```
     If (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count.    > 0)
 {
 Update ();
 }
 else {
 MessageBox.Show ("Nothing  was.     selected ");
 }
```

Comment: I have selected something. It also displays into the textbox but when i edit it, it says an error.